# Length difference between slant range and ground distance on a triangle

Tags: trigonometry

I am working on a problem that compares the slant range (hypotenuse) distance a beam emitted from a radar travels compared to the distance along the ground it has traveled.

It states that
"The effective “loss” of distance along the ground for each range gate (i.e. the difference between the slant range along the beam and the ground range) dr is then calculated for each range gate from the corresponding change in height dh with the following:"

$$
dr = \frac{dh}{tan(90^{\circ}-E)}
$$

Where E is the elevation angle of the radar (the angle above the ground the radar is pointing at.

I am having trouble figuring out where the above equaiton comes from or how it was derived. Can you help me with this?

Comment: I suggest you try asking your question [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Have you tried drawing the relevant triangle?

Comment: Yes I have tried drawing it